# Word Interop C# - Positioning Watermark in Header

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, office-addins

I'm automating a process of applying watermarks in Word documents, the watermark text will be conditionally set.

I've come across an issue when placing a watermark in a header that contains a table. The position of the watermark is pushed to the top of the page despite setting the paragraph (after the table) as the anchor for the shape.

See code snippet below:

```
foreach (Word.HeaderFooter header in section.Headers)
{
    if (header.Exists)
    {
          Word.Shape logoWatermark = null;
          if (header.Range.Tables.Count > 0)
          {
                Word.Paragraph para = header.Range.Paragraphs.Last;
                logoWatermark = header.Shapes.AddTextEffect(Office.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, 
                                "Hello World", "Arial", (float)75, Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 
                                office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0, para.Range);
          }
          else
          {
                logoWatermark = header.Shapes.AddTextEffect(Office.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, 
                                "Hello World", "Arial", (float)75, Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 
                                Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0);
          }
          
          ***Omitted Code***

          logoWatermark.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage;
          logoWatermark.RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage;
          logoWatermark.Left = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
          logoWatermark.Top = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
          logoWatermark.Rotation = -40;
          logoWatermark.WrapFormat.Type = Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapBehind;
          }
     }
}
```

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shapes.addtexteffect?view=word-pia) of the AddTextEffect methods describes the optional parameter of an range object. however it seems to be ignoring this paramter and placing the WordArt at the top left of the page.

I would very much appreciate any help or pointers to overcome this problem.

Expected result:

[image]

Actual result:

[image]

Comment: You're inserting a shape, not a watermark. The Interop object model is the same one used in VBA macros. You can record a VBA macro while you insert a watermark through the Design/Watermark to see which objects and methods are needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the macro recorder does not allow interaction with anchors when recording.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I would also like to make it clear that the interop and VBA AddTextEffect methods have different signatures https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shapes.addtexteffect

Comment: You do wrapbehind so why anchor on the para.range.  What happens if you don’t? Effectively remove the if statement?

Comment: @Boeryepes There is no change from the actual result I have shown in the question section.